# QGIS 3.2 how to save form attributes to a geopackage file?

Tags: qgis-3

I have created a geopackage file in QGIS 3.2.  I have made amendments using the layer properties>form attributes to create alias names and change the widget types to checkboxes. When I send these files for remote workers to use it doesn't save any of these changes.  It only works if I send the project which I don't want to do.  Anyone any ideas on how to save these changes to the geopackage file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is save the form to the database. In order to do this go to the layer properties, and at the bottom left you have :

[image]

And here click save as default (the third option from the top) and you will get the following:

[image]

Select the first option: Datasource Database.

It should do the trick!

Comment: Ok great to hear it! Please accept the answer : on the top left of my answer, you can upvote and accept the answer. Glad I could help!